# Can I use ".fxh" file extensions in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, shader, fxaa

In my code I have run into a problem where my program can not auto-detect which importer to use for a file I included in my content pipeline. How do I enable XNA to import .fxh files in my game?

Comment: What kind of file is a .fxh?

Comment: I do not know what an fxh file is off hand as it is the first time I have seen it. But in my case it acts like a text file that holds an extension to an fx file.

Comment: An `fxh` file is to an `fx` file as an `h` file is to a `cpp` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the file's build action to *None*.  This will prevent it from going through the Content Pipeline, but your `#include` directives should still work just fine.